# Excel VBA - autofilter by text

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I need to figure out, how to filter by one particular name.
I have two names **tichava** and **tichaval**. I want to filter out just the **tichava** one, problem is, that in some cases both names are in the same column, like this [image]

see the yellow parts. I am counting number of visible rows after the filtering is done. Problem is, that if I filter by **tichava** I also get **tichaval** if I do just equal to **tichava**, only the ones that are simply **tichava** are shown, which is wrong. What should I do? Do I need to create an Array("tichava", ", tichava", "tichava,") and filter it like this? Is there no other option?

Comment: You could use an advanced filter instead with a formula criterion, or use an additional formula column with a regular autofilter.

Comment: Rename 'tichaval' to "t__ichaval", filter on tichava.  When you have finished, rename t__ichaval to tichaval.

Comment: This feels like a pretty bruteforce thing to do, but if I cant find any other way, I will probably do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged the question `VBA`, I assume that a small VBA function is okay.

Now defining the filter in VBA has exactly the possibilities that you have when using auto filter in Excel itself - select one or more values you want to select or use advanced filters to define one or two "wildcard" (but not more that two) filters, eg *contains* or *starts with*. I don't see a way to specify an advanced filter for your exact needs.

First define a simple function

```
Public Function containsName(haystack As String, needle As String) As Boolean
    Dim words() As String, i As Long
    words = Split(Replace(haystack, " ", ""), ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(words)
        If words(i) = needle Then
            containsName = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Now this function will return `True` if the string contains *exactly* the name you are looking for. With this, you have two possibilities:

Either you use a helper column in Excel, use the function as UDF in a formula, eg `=containsName(T2, "tichava")` and filter your data by this column.

Or, if a helper column is not an option, loop over all data and create an array of all cells that you want to include and use that array as filter.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, in the end I went with renaming the parameter, and after it is counted I renamed it back.

Comment: If this is a one time job, this might be okay, but if you have to do it over and over again, maybe also with other names, this could get really annoying (and a waste of time)

Comment: I only have one nice right now, but this problem might occur in near future again, so I just bruteforce it now, but still would like to find a general solution to similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

### Filter Delimited Data

```vb
Sub FilterDelimitedData()

    Const WS_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 20
    Const CRITERION As String = "tichava"
    Const CRITERIA_DELIMITER As String = ", "

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Dim Data():
    Data = rg.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    Dim SubStrings() As String, r As Long, rStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        rStr = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If Len(rStr) > 0 Then
            SubStrings = Split(rStr, CRITERIA_DELIMITER)
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(CRITERION, SubStrings, 0)) Then
                If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then
                    dict(rStr) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    rg.AutoFilter CRITERIA_COLUMN, dict.Keys, xlFilterValues
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea to take the whole string and split it, finding the exact matching and after that filtering by them, good thinking. Did not occur to me, that I can use dictionaries a criteria1, it is basically an  Array. Can you elaborate the usage of the Dictionary? I see, that is it created , but I don't see it being filled, also never used compareMode. Where can I find more info about this? Thank you.